# Windows 10 App URL linking

Tags: windows

Does anybody know if it will be possible to link apps to URLs in Windows 10?

Like if you click a YouTube link I can choose to open it in an YouTube App rather than linking to the YouTube homepage.

Comment: Please post feature requests (or upvote didn't ones) in the Windows Feedback app.

Comment: [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781489(v=vs.85).aspx) shows how to add a "Get the app for this Web site" button when people visit your web site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible, yu might want to check this out:

[Handle URI activation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228339.aspx)